# Magento isLoggedIn return false after an ajax load

Tags: ajax, magento, session

After loading a new block with the help of Ajax, the new block does not keep the customer logged in.

This is the code currently used in my `.phtml` loaded by Ajax:

```
require_once Mage::getBaseDir('app'). '/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('');
Mage::app(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(), 'website');

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
if($session->isLoggedIn()){
    echo "in";
}else{
    echo "out";
}
```

This is how the new block is loaded (in my controller):

```
$this->loadLayout();
echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockToLoad)->toHtml();
```

**EDIT: The session is already lost before the load of the block.**

What confuses me is that I can save and load variables without any problem.
This mean that Mage is actually using the same session instance.

The following line work perfectly in my `.phtml` loaded by Ajax:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getYourVariable();
```

So what could cause the session customer to log out after an Ajax call and how can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: show the code of ajax side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from the use of a construct inside my controller.

```
    public function __construct(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract $response, array $invokeArgs = array()){
          // Some code  
    }
```

Since I had this construct, the construct from Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action wasn't getting called which caused the session to not get initiated.

So to fix this all I had to do is to call the parent construct like this:

```
    public function __construct(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract $response, array $invokeArgs = array()){
          parent::__construct($request, $response, $invokeArgs);

          // Some code  
    }
```

Note that if the construct in your controller is not needed, you can simply remove the __construct function. The Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action construct will be called automatically.

Comment: Iam also getting the same problem.Can u elaborate your answer @spirit?